# Get chrono seconds in float

Tags: c++, floating-point, c++-chrono, seconds

In the example at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono the seconds value is obtained in a `double`. This is the behavior I want. However, this appears to rely on the implicit assumption that the time point subtraction yields a value that represents seconds. I can not find anything that explains why a duration yields floating point seconds when no time units are actually specified. Without using `auto` at all, can someone show how to explicitly obtain a time unit such as seconds in a floating point type, or point me to documentation or explanation as to why the aforementioned conversion represents seconds?

The conversion in question is essentially:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> start = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> end = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start; // why does this represent seconds as opposed to some other time unit?
double secondsInDouble = elapsed_seconds.count();
```

See the following posts for examples of the conversion.

[How to get duration, as int milli's and float seconds from <chrono>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14391327/how-to-get-duration-as-int-millis-and-float-seconds-from-chrono/14391447#14391447)

[C++ chrono - get duration as float or long long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24686781/c-chrono-get-duration-as-float-or-long-long)

[getting chrono time in specific way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33613659/getting-chrono-time-in-specific-way)

[Chrono Timer Not Converting Seconds Properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710213/chrono-timer-not-converting-seconds-properly)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration the default ratio for the second template parameter is `1:1` meaning seconds.

Other values are ratios relative to that. For example the ratio for `std::chrono::milliseconds` is `1:1000` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/ratio/ratio

So this statement:

```
std::chrono::duration<double> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
```

is equivalent to:

```
std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1>> elapsed_seconds = end-start;
```

Which is defined to be seconds from which all other ratios are derived.

Whatever units `end - start` are defined in get converted to `std::ratio<1>` as in *seconds*.

If you wanted the time in milliseconds you could do:

```
std::chrono::duration<double, std::ratio<1, 1000>> elapsed_milliseconds = end-start;
```

And `end - start`  should be converted according to the new ratio.

Comment: I see the part I missed at the top of the reference: `tick period is a compile-time rational constant representing the number of seconds from one tick to the next.` So given the default ratio of 1:1, a duration period always represents one second. Thanks for bringing this to my attention.

Comment: `std::ratio<1, 1000>` can be replaced with `std::milli`.